# Iterate through json array from stomp message response (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, stomp

I get a message body response from a STOMP subscription that looks as follows:

> "[{\"name\":\"test\",\"version\":\"1.0.4\",\"lifetime\":25000}]"

to iterate through it I parse it to json and get this:

> [{"name":"test","version":"1.0.4","lifetime":25000}]

Now when I try to iterate through it I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '86' in [{"name":"test","version":"1.0.4","lifetime":25000}]

can any body help me and say what i'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
      stompClient.subscribe('/topic/validation', function(validationMessage){

        console.log(validationMessage.body);
        // --> "[{\"name\":\"test\",\"version\":\"1.0.4\",\"lifetime\":25000}]"
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(validationMessage.body);
        console.log(jsonObj);
        // --> [{"name":"test","version":"1.0.4","lifetime":25000}]

        $.each(jsonObj, function(i,item){
            console.log(item);
        });
    });
```

thanks in advance.

console log of validationMessage:

```html
Frame{
ack: (headers)arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 1name: ""prototype: frame.ack__proto__: ()<function scope>
body: ""[{\"name\":\"test\",\"version\":\"1.0.4\",\"lifetime\":25000}]""
command: "MESSAGE"
headers: Object
content-length: "99"
content-type: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
destination: "/topic/validation"
message-id: "1dm_aduc-1672"
subscription: "sub-0"__proto__: Objectnack: (headers)__proto__: 
}
```

Comment: `body: ""[{\"name\":\"test\",\"version\":\"1.0.4\",\"lifetime\":25000}]""` why this give 2 * double inverted comma?

Comment: yes that was the fault! On server side I parsed my returned Object list to String before sending the message. Then the double inverted comma is put to the response. Now I send the Object list directly without parsing it and now it works fine. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your welcome. Loved to find the sol. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the value is under `[]`. you need to go through two `$.each`

```js
var jsonObj = [{"name":"test","version":"1.0.4","lifetime":25000}];
$.each(jsonObj, function(){
    $.each(this, function(i,item){
        $('body').append('<div>'+ item +'</div>');
    });
});

var jsonObj2 = {"name":"test","version":"1.0.4","lifetime":25000}; // no []
$.each(jsonObj2 , function(i,item){
    $('body').append('<div>'+ item +'</div>');
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


var jsonObj3 = JSON.parse('[{\"name\":\"test\",\"version\":\"1.0.4\",\"lifetime\":25000}]');
                                  
$.each(jsonObj3, function(){
   $.each(this, function(i,item){
      $('body').append('<div>'+ item +'</div>');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: With the fix input for jsonObj your solution works. But when i put the validationMessage.body to jsonObj ( var jsonObj = JSON.parse(validationMessage.body)) same error message again. But the value of jsonObj is exactly the same.

Comment: thanks for your help Kanudo. This also works. But I have still the problem when I using the validationMessage.body as input. The value of it is exactly the same string you use. But it is still not possible to loop. Is it possible thats an encoding problem? thats very strange. I added the value of validationMessage to my first post.